# Install php-gmp failed on centos 7

Tags: php, centos, yum, ccxt, php-gmp

I have Centos 7 and php 7.4.16

I want to install latest version of ccxt and it need gmp  extension.

My repo list is :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * extras: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * remi-php74: mirror.23media.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
 * updates: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
repo id                                                             repo name                                                                                             status
base/7/x86_64                                                       CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                        9,933+139
epel/x86_64                                                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                        12,749+889
extras/7/x86_64                                                     CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                            498
mongodb-org-3.4/7                                                   MongoDB Repository                                                                                           125
mongodb-org-4.2/7                                                   MongoDB Repository                                                                                           103
remi-php74                                                          Remi's PHP 7.4 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                              8+413
remi-safe                                                           Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                             213+4,260
updates/7/x86_64                                                    CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                      2,559+20
zabbix/x86_64                                                       Zabbix Official Repository - x86_64                                                                          469
zabbix-non-supported/x86_64                                         Zabbix Official Repository non-supported - x86_64                                                              5
repolist: 26,662
```

Result of "yum install php-gmp" :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * extras: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * remi-php74: mirror.23media.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
 * updates: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
No package php-gmp available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What should i do ?!

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong on your side, that package is there  https://mirror.23media.com/remi/enterprise/7/php74/x86_64/repoview/php-gmp.html

Comment: I found the solution, I have to change custombuild in directadmin, thanks for your time